# Change page with data posting jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How to collect data with Javascript after change page command on jquery mobile. This is my command:

```
var resultDate = "123121312";
$.mobile.changePage("animation.html", { transition: "slidedown", type: "post", data:resultDate});
```

How to collect that data using JS on page animation.html

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html the page change related events should have the data in their parameteres.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you suggesting to me? To use some other function instead of changepage? I am using jquery mobile with phoneGap for creating native application.

Comment: The page changing events occur _after_ you call your changePage function, they are run at different times when loading the new page choose whichever fits your framework best. Keep using changePage, these you need to add to capture the data being passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).bind("pagechange",function(e,data){
    if(data.options.data){
        alert(data.options.data);
    }
});
```

That should fire on pageChange and if it's run on the page you want (obviously you need to narrow it down to that) then it will have the data variable you passed in.

You'll either need to bind/unbind it for just the page you want, or use the url variable/data to only run it on the page you want. Or you could check the data variable and only run when it is valid, as I am doing.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I was looking for. I was trying to use changePage function for changing page with data.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what you're asking for. When you run your pageChange command this will be run on your animations.html page and it will have the data you wanted to pass to it.

Comment: so I should use $.mobile.changePage("animation.html", { transition: "slidedown", type: "post", data:resultDate});

and that data would be in data.options.data?

Comment: and how that will happen if I use same JS file on both pages?

Comment: Try it out. Easier for you put it to use than for me to explain it. Programming is like 95% debugging of code.